# Definition of Full-scale error

Tags: measurement

I was looking for the concept of "Full-scale error" (related with laboratory measurement terminology) on the web without success. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I just Googled "full scale error", got some 85 million hits, and just a cursory glance at the first page showed some good stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error expressed as a percentage of full scale means that any measurement made will fall between the limits given by that quantity.

For example, an analog voltmeter with a range of zero to 100 volts specified as having an accuracy of +/-1% of full scale can be off by plus or minus 1 volt when there's between zero and 100 volts across the meter.

So, with the meter reading 1 volt, the actual input could be anything between zero and two volts, and with the meter reading 100 volts the actual input could be anywhere between 99 and 101 volts.

Comment: why is it better to state +/-1%FS , than simply say +/-1Volt ?

Comment: I don't believe it even came up, let alone being touted as "better".

Comment: i am looking for the reason why companies may choose to state the error in one way or the other...

Comment: Probably because that's the way it's done,  and everyone -  Well, almost everyone - understands what it means.

Comment: there is definitely a reason other than "it has existed like so".

Comment: OK, good luck with your "research".

Answer (score 2):

The definition varies a bit, but often it must be added to a 'zero' error, and unless otherwise specified, applies only under reference conditions- warmed up for 1 hour, ambient temperature 20°C +/-1°C or whatever. Temperature changes to scale and zero, and aging often must be added on top of that. In the case of thermocouple instruments, the cold-junction compensation is added on top (and may be specified as a ratio such as 20:1, meaning a 20°C change in ambient temperature could cause an additional 1°C error).

An error specification of **1% F.S.** means that if the scale is 4mA to 20mA, that error will not exceed +/-160uA (1% of the full scale deflection, which is 20mA-4mA = 16mA). If they're complete d*cks it could mean +/-2uA error, as I said, definitions vary.

So if the measurement is at mid-scale (12mA) then that error could be +/-2% of reading.

Comment: I think you mean the 'error will not exceed +/- 160uA '- right?

Comment: @efox29 Yes, thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, an error of 10 mV in a full-scale deflection of 2V would be a "full-scale error" of 0.5%. In other words you compare the error with the limits of measurement of the device and express that as a percentage.